# User interest Search based on Profile

Tags: javascript, php, search, user-interface

I have a

1. User login page
2. Profile Page
3. Search page (keywords are entered here,results are fetched and
   published using Google)

I use JavaScript for performing search and profile, Login page created based on PHP
I have a profile page with user interests listed, My doubt is ,I need to perform search based on user interest which is stored in profile page.

For example ,if you search normally in Google for ex: "SUN" ,the results will be related to sun ,solar system ,planets ..

For instance in user interest ,there is a category "Favorite news paper :" and answer is "SUN news report" ..so whenever the user searches "SUN" ..it should give high priority to user interest rather than general Google search results

How can i do this ,if there is any kind of code snippet there ,please help me regarding this concept.

Comment: Have you attempted it yourself? Post your attempt code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its just trick but works fine @ myside.
there is 1 input text you can take value for it from DB also..its your choice. I have call 1 function that will redirect to google..this will search on google watever you have type in input text..
if you want then you can append more string in it as you want to add its category (News paper)

**COde:**

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px;"/>
<input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search" onclick="searchLink()"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function searchLink()
{
    var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value;            
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/#q='+link1;
}
</script>
```

**Example:**

type 'facebook' in input it will redirect to google with facebook string..
if you want to add more details like 'login' along with 'facebook' then you can try like

```
function searchLink()
{
    var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value;
    link1 = link1.replace(/ /g,"+")+"+login";   
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/#q='+link1;
}
```

Hope this is right approach towards your query..

**EDIT**

Value from DB from for Favrt Sport & you can hide this if user must not see it..

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value=" *here from DB* "/>
<input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search" onclick="searchLink()"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function searchLink()
{
    var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value; 
    // here you will get watever sport he like in variable link1 

    link1 = link1.replace(/ /g,"+")+"+sport"; 
    // apend 'sport' here, you can change it according to your need

    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/#q='+link1
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you ashish for you help ,but how will this code affect search results based on user profile.if the user have a specific category in user profile like "favorite sports" and his saved answer is "football",whenever the user search sports in my application ,it should fetch and display results from google and the first priority in sports should be football ,sorry for asking like this ..but how the above code will assist me based in search based on user profile ,please reply me ,thanks in advance

Comment: favorite sports = football these both values are coming from DB?? or "favorite sports" this category is fixed/ hardcoded??

Comment: you can take whatever cateogry from DB like 'user_favrt_sports, user_favrt_news, user_favrt_drink' and fetch its value from DB. get that in JS function..split it and append in JS variable "link1" so it will redirect along with full string..

Comment: Ashish ,once again thank you so much for your assistance ,i will tell you what i have exactly ,the user profile values are coming from database ,it is not hard coded and how can i get the value from DB for search is the main problem/question ,how can i do that based on user profile ,fetching from them ..consider for example ,i have a database with a table "favorite sports" which stores values from every user and it is used for search process from that how can i append and what code should be used for search..sorry for asking this query to more detailed,but please help me regarding this thanks

Comment: you need to perform login action for each person, so you will get person_id..after login put that person_id into SESSION..so you can use that anywhere..on search page you write query for getting favrt_sport on basis of person_id from SESSION in where condition..